# How to Increment a column when adding new row into HTML Table using Java script

Tags: javascript, html, django

My requirement is to add a new blank row using java script to a table and increment one column based on previous row ( other columns need to blank) . I have tried many ways but unable to figure out.
Below is the code I am using. it works fine when I add a row for the first time but after that the cell value is not getting incremented , also please help on how to achieve copy functionality with same cell value incremented for each row copied.

can some one please help on how to fix it ?

```html
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js">
</script> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/cesiumjs/1.78/Build/Cesium/Cesium.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

   function addRow(row){
                            var i = row.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
                            var tr = document.getElementById('Table').insertRow(i+1);
                            tr.innerHTML = row.parentNode.parentNode.innerHTML;      
                            var currentShipUnit = tr.querySelector("input[name='ShipUnitId']").value;
                            console.log(currentShipUnit);

                            tr.querySelector("input[name='ShipUnitId']").value = ++currentShipUnit;
             

            }

</script>

<body>

<table id="Table" border="" class="w3-table-all">
                <thead>
                <tr class="w3-teal">
                    <th>BOX</th>
                    <th >NUMBERS</th>
                    <th >LENGTH</th>
                    <th >WIDTH</th>
                    <th >HEIGHT</th>
                    <th >WEIGHT</th>
                    <th >LEGNTH UOM</th>
                    <th >WEIGHT UOM</th>
                    <th>FEATURES</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><input size=10 type="text" readonly=True name="ShipUnitId" value='100'></td>                  
                    <td>
                        <select id="palletgid" name="palletgid" class="">
                            <option id="prb3" value="" selected></option>
                            <option value="">ABC</option>
                            <option value="">CDE</option>
                            <option value="">FRT</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td class="inputlength2" id="length"><input size=10 id="inputlength" class="inputlength" type="text" contenteditable='true' value=''></td>
                    <td id="width"><input size=10 id="inputwidth" type="text"  contenteditable='true' value=''></td>
                    <td id="height"><input size=10 id="inputheight" type="text" contenteditable='true' value=''></td>
                    <td id="weight"><input size=10 id="inputweight" type="text"  contenteditable='true' value=''></td>
                    <td id="lengthuom"><input size=10 id="inputlengthuom" type="text" contenteditable='true' value=''></td>
                    <td id="weightuom"><input size=10 id="inputweightuom" type="text" contenteditable='true' value=''></td>
                    <td>
                        <select id="" name="" class="">
                            <option id="" value="" selected></option>                           
                            <option value="">1234</option>  
                            <option value="">4555</option>    
                            <option value="">343443</option>    
                        </select>
                    </td>        
                    <td size=15>
                        <span  style="color:green" class="glyphicon glyphicon-copy" onclick="copyRow(this)"></span>
                   
                        <span  style="color:orange" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" onclick="addRow(this)"></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working using below code

```html
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js">
</script> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/cesiumjs/1.78/Build/Cesium/Cesium.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

   function addRow(tableID){                
                
                           
                var tbody = document.querySelector("#" + tableID + " tbody");
                var rowCount = tbody.rows.length;
               // console.log('rowCount '+rowCount);
                var rows = tbody.querySelectorAll("tr");                  
                     var newRow = rows[rowCount-1].cloneNode(true);               
                  var k = newRow.cells[0].children[0].value;
                  var currentNameis = newRow.cells[0].children[0].name;
                  //console.log('currentNameis '+currentNameis);
                  var currentNameisModified = currentNameis.substr(0,10)                  
                  newRow.cells[0].children[0].name = currentNameisModified + (++rowCount);
                  newRow.cells[0].children[0].value = ++k;                  
                 // console.log(newRow);
                  tbody.appendChild(newRow);
              
           }

</script>

<body>
<input type="button" value="Append Segment" onClick="addRow('TableMine')" /> 
<table id="TableMine" border="" class="w3-table-all">
                <thead class="w3-teal">                
                    <th>BOX</th>
                    <th >NUMBERS</th>
                    <th >LENGTH</th>
                    <th >WIDTH</th>
                    <th >HEIGHT</th>
                    <th >WEIGHT</th>
                    <th >LEGNTH UOM</th>
                    <th >WEIGHT UOM</th>
                    <th>FEATURES</th>
                    <th></th>               
                </thead>
                <tbody>                
                    <td>
                    <input size=10 type="text" readonly=True name="ShipUnitId" value='100'></td>                                 <td>
                        <select id="palletgid" name="palletgid" class="">
                            <option id="prb3" value="" selected></option>
                            <option value="">ABC</option>
                            <option value="">CDE</option>
                            <option value="">FRT</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td><input size=10 id="inputlength" type="text" contenteditable='true' value=''></td>
                    <td><input size=10 id="inputwidth" type="text"  contenteditable='true'value=''></td>
                    <td><input size=10 id="inputheight" type="text" contenteditable='true'value=''></td>
                    <td><input size=10 id="inputweight" type="text"  contenteditable='true' value=''></td>
                    <td><input size=10 id="inputlengthuom" type="text" contenteditable='true' value=''></td>
                    <td><input size=10 id="inputweightuom" type="text" contenteditable='true' value=''></td>
                    <td>
                        <select id="" name="" class="">
                            <option id="" value="" selected></option>                           
                            <option value="">1234</option>  
                            <option value="">4555</option>    
                            <option value="">343443</option>    
                        </select>
                    </td>        
                    <td size=15>
                        <span  style="color:green" class="glyphicon glyphicon-copy" onclick="copyRow(this)"></span>
                   
                   <span  style="color:orange" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" onclick=""></span>
                    </td>
               </tbody>
            </table>

</body>
</html>
```